# How do I add more than one text field at position north of my applet

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, textfield

I am trying to create in total three text fields at the top of my applet, two should be in line with each other and one directly below in the middle of them to so it should look like this : -_-

However, I'm sure you can only assign one component in a position so how do I go about this

```
public class JTextFieldTest extends JApplet {


public String s;
public TextField T1; 
public TextField T2; 
public void init(){
    TextField T1 = new TextField(20);
    TextField T2 = new TextField(20);
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Add word to list ");
    GreetingPanel panel = new GreetingPanel();
    add(T1, BorderLayout.NORTH); 
    add(T2, BorderLayout.NORTH); 
    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(b1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);



}

class GreetingPanel extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
    }}

   public void paint(Graphics g){
   super.paint(g);
   g.drawString(s, 20, 20);

   }

}
```

Comment: 1) check out the [Layout Manager Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). 2) Avoid mixing Swing and AWT components as you're doing.

Comment: alright thanks for that tip, so should I remove awt ?

Comment: No. Swing is built on AWT, but you shouldn't use AWT **components** with Swing GUI's. Use JTextFields not TextFields.

Comment: ohhh right sorry i'm a beginner didnt really understant, thanks for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest Layouts inside Layouts. So If you want two Buttons in the North part of your `BorderLayout` take a Layout that fits your style ant put it in. E.g. use a BorderLayout in a BorderLayout and you get more all positions of a BorderLayout in the North of your rootLayout again!

**EDIT**

So if you are totally new, I recommend to use `JavaFX` instead of `Swing`. There you easily can achieve your goal.

```
HBox hBox = new HBox();
BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();
mainPane.setTop(hBox);
hBox.getChildren().addAll(new TextField(), new Label("hi", ...);
```

There are a lot of tutorials everywhere for JavaFX, e.g. [this one here for layouts from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm#CHDGHCDG)

Comment: Actually you wouldn't be nesting "layouts" per se, but actually you would nest **JPanels**, each using its own layout.

Comment: is there any such tutorial on this as I recently started java and not sure how to do that